# How to remove Android notification icon and set backgournd like kjvBible

Tags: android, android-notifications

How can I do this?

[image]

[image]

I did this, but it didn't work:

```
val smallIconViewId = context.resources.getIdentifier(
    "left_icon", "id",
    android.R::class.java.getPackage().name
)
notificationLayout.setViewVisibility(smallIconViewId, View.INVISIBLE)
```

Comment: Could please add what is your expected output and what you are currently getting ?

Comment: Is [Expandable Notifications](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/expanded) or [Custom Notifications](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/custom-notification) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This action is banned for target SDK above 32.